# What is the best way to do a matrix style reporting in a Django App?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a number of transactions in my model:

```
Transaction      Date  Category   Amount
1                 Jan   Sales      $1000
2                 Feb   Expense    $500
3                 Jan   Expense    $500
4                 Mar   Interest   $100
```

What is the most efficient way to generate report in the template? However would you structure your queryset to get the data by month for a given year (knowing some category will be null/empty) and pass the context information in view.py? I know this is an easy questions but I'm curious what is the most efficient way to implement this matrix reporting?

```
    Category          Jan       Feb      Mar

    Sales            $1000

    Expenses         $500       $500

    Interest                            $100

    Total            $500       -$500   $100
```